# Method on ruby model not accessing property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model item which contains a source url

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :price, :priority,:picture,:url
    belongs_to :user

    validates :url, format: /(^$)|(^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$)/ix
    validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

    #default_scope {where "completed<>trued"}

    def source
            hostname=@url.split('/')[2]
            hostname["www."]=""
            hostname


    end

end
```

and I use this in the indexview

```
    <a href="<%=item.url%>"><%=item.source %></a>
```

So I can access item.url fine. but item.source throws an exception:

> undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

I think this is because source method is not accessing the url property. How do I make it do that? I am assuming this is how its supposed to work in ruby. Might be I am making a blunder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@url` try `self.url.` or simply `url.`  because it's  object attributes.

Comment: also, why  does it throw a null pointer exception.I thought @var and self.var were the same things

Answer (score 2):

Where does `@url` come from?
Maybe you mean:

```
self.url
```

Comment: Is it not used for accessing class properties? like in java/c++
class abc{String url; function getUrl(){return this.url}}. Is it not a replacement for that @url=this.url?